# How to Resize an Image in Body CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize the body image of my site so that it doesn't take up the whole page. How do I resize it? I'm not sure of the code so I just have the image URL displayed. I want it so that white space shows beneath the image declaring its max height and not so it spans the page.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(C:/Users/Gabriel/Downloads/Green-blur.jpg);
  background-repeat: none;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul id="nav">
      <li id="brand"><a href="#">MINIMAL</a></li>
      <li id="navm"><a href="#">Men</a></li>
      <li id="navm"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li id="navm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>Simplicity is Minimal</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="home">
    <a href="#" id="homeb">Shop Now</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

FIXED with background-repeat:none;

Comment: I'm not sure what percentage of the page you want to cover with the image.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these css rules for your body:

```
body {
  background: url(C:/Users/Gabriel/Downloads/Green-blur.jpg);
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  background-size: 69px 54px; // with the first value being the width; second value the height
  // following rules are optional, don't know if you need them in your case
  // background-position: center;   
  // background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Note that the values of background-size can be declared as percentage values as well.
And if you want to let the image start from somewhere specific on the page, you can use

```
background-position: top right; // default is top left
```

feel free to let me know if it worked or not

Comment: It works but what happens is it multiplies and repeats constantly to cover the whole screen

Comment: @Gabriel Pozo That is why I added the "background-repeat: no-repeat;", this makes sure that the background image is only rendered once (and does not multiply, like you say)

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to your body style in css

```
background-size: 100px 200px; // first value difines width and second value, height
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, it will surely help you.

```
body {
  background-image: url(C:/Users/Gabriel/Downloads/Green-blur.jpg);
  background-size: 50% 80%; // you can change % value as per your requirement
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works however the image starts to duplicate and repeat. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can add one more property in this.
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`
Hope it will work for you.